# MCP home range overlap

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate home range overlap among a batch of animals that I have estimated home ranges for through both the MCP and kernelUD methods in the adehabitatHR package. I realize there is a function for calculating overlap with the kernel method, but can anyone tell me how best to calculate overlap for MCP?

I gather the rgeos package has a gIntersection function that I have begun to play around with.
Has anyone come up with a relatively straightforward method/code - whether in adehabitatHR, regeos, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this helps:

```
library(adehabitatHR)
library(rgeos)

## Use some simulated data
ani1 <- SpatialPoints(matrix(rnorm(200, mean=2), ncol=2))
ani2 <- SpatialPoints(matrix(rnorm(200, mean=1), ncol=2))

## Function to calculate overlaps
gOverlap <- function(hr1, hr2, ...) {
  a <- gIntersection(hr1, hr2, ...)
  if (is.null(a)) {
    return(0)
  }
  gArea(a, byid=TRUE) / gArea(hr1, byid=TRUE) 
}

## Calcualte homeranges
hr1 <- mcp(ani1)
hr2 <- mcp(ani2)

## Calculate HR overlap
gOverlap(hr1, hr2)
```

Comment: I ended up making a separate SpatialPolygonDataFrame for each animal in adehabitatHR.

Amcp <- mcp(Aloc[,1], percent=95)
Bmcp <- mcp(Bloc[,1], percent=95)

##Then used rgeo’s gIntersection function to calculate overlap for each possible combination of pairs. 

AB<- gIntersection(Amcp, Bmcp, byid=TRUE)
AB
plot(Amcp, axes=TRUE)
plot(Bmcp, lty=2, add=TRUE)
plot(ABl, add=TRUE, pch=16, col='red')

This was quite cumbersome and tedious, so thanks for posting another suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Running overlap for single pairs at once can be very inefficient when you have many animals or many collaring sessions.  I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this (and I welcome suggestions on refinements!), but this worked for me:

```
#Relevant libraries (I think they're all here!)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(geosphere)
library(rgeos)
library(nlme)

#Define an overlap function for a single dyad
dyad.overlap <- function(cp,dyads.df){
   p1<-subset(cp, cp@data$id==dyads.df[1])
   p2<-subset(cp, cp@data$id==dyads.df[2])
   Overlap<- ifelse(is.null(gIntersection(p1,p2)), 0, gArea(gIntersection(p1,p2)) / gArea(p1)) #puts 0 if no overlap between the dyad
   return(Overlap)
}

#Define a function for overlap of all animals from a given time period
mcp.overlaps <- function(period.df){
   period.df$Animal<-factor(period.df$Animal)   #remove any ids not relevant to that period
   count <- length(unique(period.df$Animal))  #identify number of individuals for the period
   anim <- unique(period.df$Animal) #identify names of individuals/periods
   xy<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(period.df[c("Easting","Southing")], data=data.frame(id=period.df$Animal)) #create SPDF
   proj4string(xy)<-CRS("+init=epsg:32750")   #define projection
   cp <- adehabitatHR::mcp(xy, percent=95)  #create Spatial Polygons Data Frame of the 95% MCPs
   writeOGR(obj=cp, dsn="tempdir", layer=paste(period.df$file_folder[i],"95 Percent MCPs"), driver="ESRI Shapefile")  #export shp of 95% MCPs for period, if desired
   dyads<-(combn(anim, 2, simplify=T))  #all possible dyad combinations
   dyads.df<-data.frame(A1=dyads[1,1:count],A2=dyads[2,1:count]) #creates a data frame of the pairs
   dyads.df$Overlap<-apply(dyads.df, 1, dyad.overlap, cp=cp)
   dyads.df$Period<-period.df$file_folder[1]
   return(dyads.df)
}

#Now run the overlap for each time period included in the data frame  
All.Overlaps<-do.call(rbind.data.frame, gapply(df, groups=df$file_folder, FUN=mcp.overlaps))
```

Of course, if you only have a single time period (e.g., a year of data and looking at annual home ranges), all you have to do is:

```
All.Overlaps <- mcp.overlaps(df)
```

This assumes that all data is in a single data frame (df), with the variables defined as following (adjust names to suit your data):

- file_folder: collaring period/session of interest
- Animal: unique identifier for an individual
- Easting/Southing: your lat long coordinates (be sure to adjust the projection as needed)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a little the Johannes' answer, maybe it helps a little more:

```
library(adehabitatHR)
library(rgeos)

data(puechabonsp)
rel <-  puechabonsp$relocs
cp <- mcp(rel[,1])

## Set Up a matrix which will store the results
mat <- matrix(NA,4,4,dimnames=list(c("1","2","3","4"), 
                                   c("1","2","3","4")))

## Set Up the loop
gOverlap <- function(hr, number, matrix){
  for(i in c(1:number)){
    for(j in c(1:number)){
      a <- gIntersection(hr[i,], hr[j,])
      if (is.null(a)){
      matrix[i, j] <- 0
        } else{matrix[i, j] <- gArea(a)}
      }
    }
  return(matrix)
 }

##Test the function
gOverlap(cp, 4, mat)
##Plotting to corroborate
plot(cp)
```

The output is a matrix with every intersection, and to obtain the total overlap you only have to sum row or columns without the self-intersection. Finally, you can add or delete individuals just modifying the initial matrix.

All the best,